# Flatten subviews

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have a graphics app I am writing that has a UIView that has several UIImageViews as subviews added to it over time.
I want to flatten all these subviews for performance reasons as it is slowing down over time. What is the simplest way to "flatten" these layers.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "flatten."  Can you describe the performance limitations you're encountering and why "flattening" the views will fix these problems?  Is flattening a graphical distortion, or do you mean combining the views into a single view?

Comment: Neil, I'm pretty sure he means "composite all the separate images into one image" (which is often called flattening in Photoshop, et al when dealing with layers). My response is based on that assumption

Answer (score 2):

Create a new bitmap context:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGContextRef newContext =
    CGBitmapContextCreate(
        NULL,
        viewContainingAllUIImageViews.frame.size.width,
        vViewContainingAllUIImageViews.frame.size.height,
        8,
        viewContainingAllUIImageViews.frame.size.width,
        colorspace,
        0);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
```

Paint the appropriate background into the context:

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(newContext, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(newContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, viewContainingAllUIImageViews.frame.size.width, vViewContainingAllUIImageViews.frame.size.height));
```

Get the `CGImage` property of each image that your `UIImageView` contains and draw all of the images into this single image:

```
CGContextDrawImage(newContext, oneOfTheSubImageViews.frame, oneOfTheSubImageViews.image.CGImage);
```

Convert the bitmap context back into an image:

```
CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);
UIImage *flattenedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage];
```

Then `CFRelease` `newContext`, `newImage`, use the `UIImage` in a `UIImageView` and discard all other `UIImageView`s.

Comment: Thanks Matt.

That has been very helpfull. I am integrating parts of that into my code.

Comment: I found one more option: to just render the entire parent view's layer instead of looping through each subview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869692/iphone-flattening-a-uiimageview-and-subviews-to-image-blank-image either way should work fine though.