# How can I get a LIVE screenshot programmatically, when my App is running?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I just want to share a screen shoot of an UIView vie email, FB or what ever users want!
The below code only takes a original of UIView with no inputed texts nor changed images

```
CGRect rect = [mainView bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [mainView.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869692/iphone-flattening-a-uiimageview-and-subviews-to-image-blank-image/3869804#3869804

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use one of the solutions at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically) depending on whether it's a retina device or not.